# Can we store echoed text in a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

When I call a function of another class (in a included file), some text is being output with `echo`. I need to store this in a variable.

Here is the code:

```
require_once('../restapis/api.php');

class ApiTest
{
    public function testapis(){
       $api = new Api();
       $api->validate_request();
    }
}

$obj = new ApiTest();
$obj->testapis();
```

And I am getting a JSON string echoed in browser:

```
{"ERRORCODE":"E032","ERRORMESSAGE":"Invalid URL."}
```

I don't have permission to change anything in the `api.php` file, that's why I can't change `echo` to `return`.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: So where do you need access to it?

Comment: actually i need to write test case using phpunit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
ob_start(); // Activate output buffering

$obj->testapis(); // Whatever code whose output you want to capture

$contents = ob_get_contents(); // Store buffered contents

ob_end_clean(); // Deactivate output buffering
```

After that, `$contents` will contain the echoed output.